# Connection timed out when uploading artifact to Nexus repository via Gitlab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: maven, gitlab, pom.xml, nexus

I am using Gitlab CI/CD pipeline to compile a code and upload the generated artifact to a Nexus repositoy.
But I am getting below error while executing mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true in gitlab-ci.yml

[ MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode" ]

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default- 
 deploy) on project demo: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven- 
 metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to 
 snapshots (http://localhost:8081/repository/Test_gitlab_nexus/): Transfer failed for 
 http://localhost:8081/repository/Test_gitlab_nexus/com/example/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven- 
 metadata.xml: Connect to localhost:8081 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: 
 Connection refused -> [Help 1]
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

Below is the pom.xml used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
<repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>Central</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/Test_gitlab_nexus/</url>
   <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
    </snapshots>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
    </releases>
</repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
 <snapshotRepository>
   <id>snapshots</id>
   <name>Snapshots</name>
   <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/Test_gitlab_nexus/</url>
 </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I don't see timeout anywhere it's simply `Connection refused -` ...that means the repository manager is not correctly configured etc.  If you have a repository manager (presumably nexus) you should have one entry for snapshots and one for releases in your distributionManagement... which  are here the same which I doubt that  it is correct.

Comment: Thanks....my bad, actually there was a Connection timed out error too but had made some changes..probably the error changed. Could you please elaborate on "you should have one entry for snapshots and one for releases in your distributionManagement." ?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management

Comment: I changed the urls for central and snapshot, but it still gives the same error.